# Espacio inutil al particionar disco para ubuntu junto windows

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows10

Estoy teniendo un problema al tratar de instalar ubuntu en un pc recién comprado 'nuevo' con windows 10 pro. Ya lo he hecho varias veces y nunca he tenido este problema. He modificado la BIOS, he puesto BOOT secuence en UEFI, desabilitado el Enabled Legacy ROM y el SECURITY BOOT ENABLED.
Hasta ahí bien porque cuando introduzco el USB con la IOS arranca el Ubuntu. Por lo tanto no creo que el problema sea en la BIOS.
Bueno cuando llego al tercer paso donde te da la opción de instalar el Ubuntu formateando el disco o crear la particiones manualmente me aparece la primera sorpresa. Por que no me reconoce que tengo el windows 10, por lo que la primera opción formatearía el disco entero y instalaría el Ubuntu. Eso no quiero hacerlo, por lo que intento la segunda opción, crear las particiones manualmente.
El disco esta con tres particiones primarias, la de arranque windows, windows y la de recobery. Como digo el pc tiene un día, esta virgen. Para hacerle hueco al Ubuntu desde windows usando el administrador de discos hice una reducción de la partición de windows.El PC tiene 1 tb y la reduje a 500 dejando unos 400 GB para Ubuntu.
Cuando intento hacer las particiones en la instalación en esta partición y creo /boot el resto de la partición me dice espacio inutil.Y ya no puedo seguir. Llevo un par de días intentandolo y no lo consigo.
Alguna idea que puedo estar haciendo mal.

Hola Marce@Puente voy a subir una imagen de como esta el disco duro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando creo en la partición sin asignar /boot como primaría de unos 2GB es cuando el resto de la partición aparece como espacio inutil.

Hola Marce@Puente ya lo conseguido. A ver lo que hice fue particionar el disco el dos mitades una formateada ntfs y la segunda ext4. En la primera instale el Windows y en la segunda el ubuntu. Y me arrancan los dos sin problemas.

Cuando llegue a la instalación del Ubuntu en el paso de donde quería instalarlo si que me aparecieron las tres opciones, instalarlo junto a windows boot options, 'esta opción no me aparecía antes', la de formatear disco  duro he instalar Ubuntu y la tercera la de particionado manual. Ahora si me dejaba particionar como yo quería. De todas formas elegí la de instalar junto a Windows por no arriesgarme. El disco que ha quedado así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve ha creado dos particiones /dev/sda5 y /dev/sda6. Lo que no tengo claro es la /dev/sda5 para que es.  En la imagen no se si se ve pero debajo pone que contiene '/,/var/snap/swapfile/firefox...'.No se por que ha creado /dev/sda5.

Otra cosa que te quería comentar que leí el enlace que me pasaste y la pega de no crear la partición /swap es que entonces no puedes hibernar Ubuntu.

Comment: Hola Carlos, tu disco tiene una partición "EFI"?.

Comment: Hola Marce@Puente. No estoy seguro que no, pero aun asi tengo 3 primarias mas la extendida que hacen 4, ese es el tope. Luego dentro de la extendida creo /boot tambien como primaria y ya me sale el resto como inutil.

Comment: Hola Carlos, selecciona "***sin asignar***", abajo a la izquierda hay un botón **+**, dale y te aparece una ventana donde creas la nueva partición, podes elegir ***ext4** para el sistema de archivos, tamaño el máximo que te permita, marcala para formatear (no se si ahí o afuera) y asignale como punto de montaje "**/**" (sin comillas). Luego le das a instalar... y contame.

Comment: Buenos días Marce@Puente, gracias por seguir el hilo. Vale te cuento, he llamado al servicio técnico del PC y hemos intentado reiniciar Windows. Ha sido imposible y me ha dicho que lo reinstale. Me he descargado la ISO para volver a hacerlo. Es tarde, ya no voy a ponerme a ello ahora porque entro a las 1400 a trabajar, lo instalare esta noche. Le he comentado el tema de instalar Ubuntu y me ha dicho que ahora es el momento adecuado para hacer las particiones. Que me recomiendas . Y otra cosa quiero instalar el Ubuntu con particiones personalizadas, osea /boot, swap, /, /home.

Comment: Debería formatear con gparted el disco antes de ponerme a instalar el windows??

Comment: Y creo que si, la verdad es que no me acuerdo del instalador de "W", pero igual está bien con gParted, crea una partición para boot (fat32) de 200MB, otra para "W" (ntfs) de lo que te parezca y deja el resto vacio. Después cuando instalas Ubuntu, creas la nueva partición, no se que ubuntu vas a instalar, pero los nuevos no usan partición swap (o al menos no es necesaria). Igual si queres perder 20 nim, intenta instalar ubuntu, la mayoría de las veces, "W" no arranca porque se "rompio" el boot, y linux lo arregla.

Comment: Hola Marce@Puente esta noche probare a instalar ubuntu a ver si soluciona el problema del arranque de win. Por probar suerte como dice GOOGLE. Bueno voy a instalar la version 22.10.Donde has leido eso de que ya no hace falta la particion swap en las nuevas versiones

Comment: La verdad es medio viejito el tema, te dejo un [enlace](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234838/is-it-necessary-to-have-a-home-and-swap-partitions-in-20-04) que busqué ahora, desde el 2020 que no es necesario, yo no me acuerdo lo que hice ayer... imaginate de lo que leí hace 3 años!!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu pantalla de particionado debería verse más o menos así:

| Dispositivo | Tipo | PuntoMontaje | formatear? | Tamaño | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /dev/sda |  |  |  |  |  |
| /dev/sda1 | ntfs | boot |  | 500MB |  |
| /dev/sda2 | ntfs |  |  | 500GB |  |
| espacio libre |  |  |  |  |  |

le das a crear partición le asignas "ext4" como sistema de ficheros, el tamaño y el punto de montaje "/", una vez hecho, deberías ver esto:

| Dispositivo | Tipo | PuntoMontaje | formatear? | Tamaño | etc... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| /dev/sda |  |  |  |  |  |
| /dev/sda1 | ntfs |  |  | 500MB |  |
| /dev/sda2 | ntfs |  |  | 500GB |  |
| /dev/sda3 | ext4 | / |  | 500GB |  |

si no es así, porfa, sube una imagen de lo que tienes.

Comment: Hola Marce@Puente ayer trabaje y no pude responderte.Vale ahora tengo un problema mayor y es que  no me arranca el windows. He reseteado la BIOS y todo y no hay forma de que arranque. Me responde 'NO BOOT DEVICE FOUND' y el tema es que tengo que llevarlo a que le pongan una unidad de CD que se les olvido. A ver que les digo!! . He probado todas la combinaciones en boot secuence  con Legacy y UEFI, también he habilitado y desabilitado ENabled Legacy options Roms y el secure boot enable y nada no me carga el windows. Cuando reseteo la Bios se queda en Legacy

Comment: No creo que sea un problema, si lográs instalar Ubuntu, automáticamente te configura el arranque de Windows. (salvo que se haya corrompido el sistema de archivos).